# How to configure MacPort to pick already installed packages

Tags: macos, macports

I have recently shifted to OSX environment, so don't know much about MacPorts.

Is there a way to tell MacPorts to pick already installed packages. For instance to install

> sudo port install meld

its requiring hell lot of packages, including python2.6. But I already have python2.6 installed.

Comment: use [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) instead

Comment: Homebrew doesn't have meld in it

Comment: In my experience, installing GUIs via MacPorts hugely increases the install footprint. You can find the latest version of [`meld`](https://github.com/yousseb/meld) at GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isnt. If you want to link against system installations then use Homebrew or compile manually yourself. Personally i prefer Macports because its completely isolated. Ive got plenty of disk so having duplicates doesnt bother me.